# Frame rate functions in python

Tags: python, frame-rate

I was hoping I could get some help on a piece of python code that I've been working on. What I'm trying to do is assess the frame rate during a task on a stimulus presentation software that is python-based. Here's what I have :

```
frame1 = 0.0152
frame2 = visual.getMsPerFrame(win, nFrames = 60, showVisual=False, msg='', msDelay=0.0)
frame3 = frame2 - frame1
```

The problem I'm having is that "frame2" yields a set of numbers. Specifically, it will yield the average, median, and standard deviation. Because of this, "frame3" will crash. Is there anyway to pull out just the average value out of the `getMsPerFrame()` output so that "frame3" will actually run?

I'm pretty new to programming so I'm not too familiar with this stuff.

Comment: Can you add the output of `print(frame2)` ?

Comment: What graphics or UI toolkit are you using? I suspect most answers will need to be specific to a given one. See if there's a tag!

Comment: I think I found the library you are using is it PsychoPy?  If so I've updated my answer

Comment: Yes, it was psychopy. Wow the answer below is amazing it was exactly what I needed to finish writing my piece of code. I really appreciate all the help. Very thorough !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the [psychopy](http://www.psychopy.org/) module, whihc according to it's [source code](http://psychopy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/psychopy/visual.py) shows that `getMsPerFrame()` returns:

```
return msPFavg, msPFstd, msPFmed #, msdrawAvg, msdrawSD, msfree
```

The Hash sign (`#`) is a comment in Python so this means the returned values are a tuple.  You can access the desired value the same way you wold if the return value was array like so:

```
>>> print(getMsPerFrame())
(123, 90, 154)
>>> print(getMsPerFrame()[0])
123
```

As you can see this is rather bad design because it requires a reading of the source code to understand the meaning of the number you are after.  I'm leaving the original answer in case you find yourself in a similar situation in the future.

---

If `visual.getMsPerFrame()` returned a Dict like this:

```
>>> print(frame2)
{'max': 154, 'avg': 123, 'min': 90}
```

Then you can access part of it by name like this:

```
>>> print(frame['avg'])
123
```

If it returned an array like this:

```
>>> print(frame2)
[154, 123, 90]
```

Then you would have to know which element was the avg.  Assuming the 2nd it would look like this (arrays are zero indexed):

```
>>> print(frame[1])
123
```

If it returned an array of dicts like this:

```
>>> print(frame2)
[{'max': 154}, {'avg': 123}, {'min': 90}]
```

You could use list comprehension like this:

```
>>> print([item['avg'] for item in frame2 if item.keys()[0] == 'avg'][0])
123
```

(OK this is getting kind of silly, please just post the output of `print(frames2)`)  Ok one more (I am having a lot of fun learning Python these days) how about a list of tuples like this:

```
>>> print(frame2)
[('max', 154), ('avg', 123), ('min', 90)]
```

Here the list comprehension is a little easier to follow:

```
>>> print([value for key, value in frame2 if key=='avg'][0])
123
```